# SeekBar progress not keeping up with large custom thumb

Tags: android, android-layout, seekbar, android-seekbar, seekbar-thumb

I have implemented a simple SeekBar whose thumb gets large while the user touches it. While this works fine in Marshmallow devices, it doesn't on Lollipop.

**In Marshmallow-** (This is how it should be)
[image: Default thumb- Appears correctly]
On touch-
[image: Enlarged thumb- Appears correctly]

**In Lollipop-** (This is wrong)
[image]

**The two problems are-**

1. The thumb is no longer vertically centered.
2. The progress doesn't visibly change while the user is touching the thumb.

**Here is my activity layout-**

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipChildren="false">

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar_main_green"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:max="255"
            android:thumb="@drawable/custom_thumb_green" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Here is my class-**

```
sbGreen.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            // Changing background color of some other view
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            sbGreen.setThumb(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.custom_thumb_green_large));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            sbGreen.setThumb(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.custom_thumb_green));
        }
    });
```

**Here are my drawables-**
custom_thumb-

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp" >

        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:width="10dp"
                android:height="10dp" />
            <solid android:color="#00af00" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#50008000"/>
            <size android:height="20dp" android:width="20dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

custom_thumb_large-

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="30dp"
        android:left="30dp"
        android:right="30dp"
        android:top="30dp" >

        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:width="10dp"
                android:height="10dp" />
            <solid android:color="#00af00" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#50008000"/>
            <size android:height="40dp" android:width="40dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Things I have tried-**

- Set `maxHeight` to large value as mentioned here-
  [stackoverflow- how to fix seekbar bar thumb centering issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404100/how-to-fix-seekbar-bar-thumb-centering-issues)
- Set `minHeight` and `maxHeight` equal or less than `layout_height` as mentioned above and here- [stackoverflow- custom seekbar thumb vertical position issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18722913/custom-seekbar-thumb-vertical-position-issue)
- Looked here but I am not using any custom progress drawable-
  [stackoverflow- android marshmallow custom seekbar progress bar not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35273071/android-marshmallow-custom-seekbar-progress-bar-not-showing)

Any help or suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: try to use sp instead of dp

Comment: @Saret Replaced all `dp` with `sp`. No effect

Comment: have you solve this ? I met the same problem

Comment: No i haven't. Moved on from lollipop